# Hierarchical navigation w/ Scala in the Play! framework

Tags: mysql, scala, tree, playframework, nested-sets

I need to implement a hierarchy of categories (basically a tree structure). As I am new to Scala, I suspect there is a very good functional approach to this problem.

I have used nested sets in PHP/mysql before. Is there an easy way to create a tree structure that enables me to easily retrieve parent and child nodes from the tree, starting out from a database table that consists of

id
parent_id
label

?

My feeling is that this is where Scala should shine with its functional flavour.